# Use the YouTube API to retrieve music from the Audio Library

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm looking for a solution to be able to retrieve music from the Audio Library on YouTube. The Audio Library section on YouTube allows you to filter by genre and attribution requirements. Can someone confirm if this is exposed via their API? I haven't seen any documentation addressing this.

Comment: I don't think so, but, if you're interested, check this link: [YouTube Audio Library Downloader - GitHub](https://github.com/Ragnarokkr/youtube-audio-library-downloader) or search `Audio Library YouTube API` on Google - that's how I got the previous link. N.B: not my project and I haven't tried yet. Hope it helps somehow.