# Does the YouTube Audio Library have an API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to make an app to help YouTube content creators add royalty free music to their videos that they will be sharing on YouTube.

I am wondering if the YouTube API has been updated to provide a way for developers to access the music from the Audio Library.

I see that there were two similar questions asked over 2 years ago

[List and download videos from youtube audio library in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65350631/list-and-download-videos-from-youtube-audio-library-in-python)

[Use the YouTube API to retrieve music from the Audio Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404335/use-the-youtube-api-to-retrieve-music-from-the-audio-library)

If not, is there any other royalty free music API that I could integrate into an App which content developers can share music to YouTube. It seems that with some royalty free music APIs (like Epidemic) you have to declare which social channels the music is being shared to, but what if you don't know where users of your app will be sharing the music to? Is there an API that has broad use like the YouTube audio library?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for such API myself. Here are my findings as of today:

Youtube

- does not provide API for music search, you can check all available APIs here  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/?apix=true
- however, it seems you only need song ID to construct the url to play / download audio item from the lib i.e. https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1KAk_m-PLFD8oT5EJ2JDBqx_Q0TqCeSEx (inspired by https://github.com/Ragnarokkr/youtube-audio-library-downloader)

Other

- https://docs.saavn.me/search/songs/ free and anonymous
- https://freesound.org/help/developers/ provides free API, search is simple, download requires OAuth2 implementation
- https://www.discogs.com/developers simple search, OAuth for download
- https://pixabay.com/music/ has no music API yet (does have for image and video), but I hope they will add it soon https://pixabay.com/forum/support-help-28/api-status-of-music-api-14462/, add your vote