# Youtube audio library item as google drive ID

Tags: youtube

I am looking for an API or other undocumented way to resolve entries from [youtube audio library](https://youtube.com/audiolibrary) into google drive file ID. Most likely this is something undocumented as [youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/?apix=true) docs doesnt seem to cover it.

I have recently stumbled upon [this repo](https://github.com/ThibaultJanBeyer/YouTube-Free-Audio-Library-API/blob/master/songs/1.js) where there are drive IDs matching the youtube audio library entries, unfortunately the author does not remember anymore.

With the drive ID, once can simply construct url to play/download the audio like https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1KAk_m-PLFD8oT5EJ2JDBqx_Q0TqCeSEx

Comment: *does not remember anymore* you mean *does not respond anymore*? For others, note [your answer on a similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77745442).

Comment: I have been working on [a similar project](https://gitea.lemnoslife.com/Benjamin_Loison/YouTube_Audio_library_extractor) but have not enough time recently to stabilize it.

Comment: ...the repo owner does not remember how he obtained these .json files. I am looking into your project, but can not find a place where your resolve drive file ID, is there any place in code I missed?

Comment: I just precised the repository state in the [`README.md`](https://gitea.lemnoslife.com/Benjamin_Loison/YouTube_Audio_library_extractor/src/commit/49c5e29c39876aa376aaf9ccc78262bd8d11f96a/README.md), as far as I know Google Drive is not involved in YouTube UI, hence here are [my current speculations](https://gitea.lemnoslife.com/Benjamin_Loison/YouTube_Audio_library_extractor/issues/5) about Google Drive beind used in [the repository you mentioned](https://github.com/ThibaultJanBeyer/YouTube-Free-Audio-Library-API), let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: However, [as I precised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77750458/youtube-audio-library-item-as-google-drive-id#comment137073412_77750458) be aware that I do not have enough time working on this topic currently, hence I am only able to answer questions I currently have the answer to.